# Google Tag Manager Enhanced ecommerce is set up but does not show results in tha GA dashboard

Tags: google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

I have set up Google Tag Manager enhanced ecommerce exactly like what this tutoria says: [the tutorial](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/enhanced-ecommerce-guide-for-google-tag-manager/#add-to-cart)

and it is working great and shows this in my debug console using the tag manager preview feature

[image]
the problem is that the data that I am adding is not showing in Google Analytics ecommerce dashboard, I have activated the enhanced ecommerce in Google Analytics too, and the problem is not it. any ideas?
this is my ecommerce dashboard in google analytics:

[image]

Comment: Do you see events with the provided 'Ecommerce' event category in the Behaviour > Events > Top events report for the same period?

Comment: @kgrg yes I see it there

Comment: So the event gets sent to GA. Can you check the actual payload of this event, while debugging GTM? Either in Network tab of developer console, or you can also use the GTM debug view. Do you see your ecommerce data, when you click 'Show more', as seen on your first picture?

Comment: @kgrg yes I can see the ecommerce data and they are in correct format

Comment: What type of ecommerce event is this? (Transaction, add to cart, etc.) Can you maybe share the payload of this event from the Network tab?